# Sum of Series given another

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given that: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}= \frac{\pi^4}{90}$$
Find the sum of:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^4}$$

Answer (score 5):

It is given that ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}{1\over {n^4}}={{\pi}^2\over 90}$

We have to find $${\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}{1\over {(2n+1)^4}}$$
$$={\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}{1\over {n^4}}-{1\over {(2n)^4}}$$
$$={\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}{1\over {n^4}}-{1\over 16}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}{1\over {n^4}}$$
$$={{\pi}^2\over 90}\times {15\over 16}$$
$$={{\pi}^2\over 96}$$